# Proof by induction with unknown formula?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I've got a math question on induction and I'm not sure how to solve it. Would anyone be able to give me some tips or do a step by step of how I'd be able to solve it?

The question goes as follows:

> You are given $n$ envelopes, numbered $0$, $1$, $\ldots$, $n-1$. Envelope $0$ contains $2^0 = 1$ pound sterling, envelope $1$ contains $2^1 = 2$ pounds, envelope $2$ contains $2^2 = 4$ pounds, $\ldots$, and envelope $n − 1$ contains $2^{n−1}$ pounds. Let $P(n)$ be the assertion that: For all non negative integers $k < 2^n$, there is a subset of the $n$ envelopes whose contents total to exactly $k$ pounds.
>   Prove by induction that $P(n)$ holds for all integers $n \geq 1$. Hint: Keep in mind that $2^{n−1} + 2^{n−1} = 2 \cdot 2^{n−1} = 2^n$ and consider three cases $k < 2^{n−1}$, $k = 2^{n−1}$, and $2^{n−1} < k < 2^n$ in the inductive step.

Anyone got any tips/advice on how to solve it? I had a look at how to do induction proof, and I found out that I need to do the base case ($n=1$), then suppose for $n=k$ and then prove for $n=k+1$, but the examples I looked at all had a formula, and this doesn't have one so I'm not sure how to do it or even how to get the base case.

Comment: The heck with induction.  Write the number with in base 2 and the proof is nearly immediate.

Comment: So to start, consider when $n=1$. Then P(1) is the assertion that for all nonnegative integers $k<2^1=2$, there is a subset of $n$ envelopes that total $k$ pounds. Since $k<2$, we must have $k=1$. Moreover, you are given 1 envelope since $n=1$, and that envelope has $2^0$ pounds. This single envelope is the subset of $n$ envelopes that holds one pound. This is the base case.

Comment: I agree with @WilliamElliot on this. Write $k$ in binary and each slot will tell you which envelope to select. For example, to obtain $21$ quid, write $21 = (10101)_2$ and select the 16, 4, and 1 pound envelopes.

Comment: I think this is given as an exercise for induction regardless of other possible ways of doing it. There is a comment about establishing the base case. Then there is quite a big hint in the actual question - some of the $k$ you can do without the new envelope, one of the new target numbers is a power of $2$ and you need also to work out how to do the larger numbers which aren't a power of $2$. You might write out the cases for three envelopes and four envelopes to see what is happening, but I think you need to give it a go.